# The Job Scheduling service design

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, microservices, job-scheduling

There is an idea to create a system built on multiple domain micro services and some services doing additional stuff like, let's say, the job scheduling service. The idea here is to be able to schedule any job from any micro service, so it shouldn't be a big deal to schedule new jobs from a new micro service if it's added to the system.

First of all, what I'm worrying about is an ability to create such service which seems to be independent from domain micro services and another thing is to abstract the service enough, so that the clients wouldn't know how the service is implemented, which job scheduling library it's using etc. I'm afraid that it's impossible to implement what I want.

For instance, I have a micro service which needs to send an email with specific content every Friday and another micro service wants to schedule another job. So they both are going to communicate with the job scheduling service I want to implement. Is there any architecture solutions to achieve this?

Sorry for being too abstract, I described the problem as I understand it myself. I hope your hints and thought will help me to find the best approach to have functionality like this. Maybe some libraries provide the functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're describing, you should be using events and a single service to encapsulate that part of the domain. For example, with something like emails, you should have an email service that listens for events and then sends particular emails for particular events.

Let's say you're doing user registration, for example, when a user signs up, you might have a user service that actually creates the user record. That service would send a "UserCreated" event when it's done. The email service, then, would respond to "UserCreated" events by sending out a welcome email to the user. You might have other services that also respond to the same events, as well. This abstraction allows you to separate the logic of creating a new user from the tasks that need to happen after a new user is created, which is not the domain of the user service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up a controller on top of your microservices architecture. I'll use Docker and Kubernetes as an example.

What this would look like:

Controller (job scheduler) - sits on top of the arch controlling the deployment schedule
* Kubernetes / Docker Swarm - coordinates scale of containers
* Docker containers

The controller will allow you to have visibility across your network. It will be able to coordinate your Kubernetes / Docker Swarm deployment strategy. And you can place agents inside Docker containers with the ability to scale up or down based on your needs with preferred configurations.

You can look at the below links for a quick video on sample architecture. Full disclosure, I am an engineer at Stonebranch

[Cloud Orchestration](https://www.stonebranch.com/solutions/cloud-automation/)

[Docker Workload Automation](https://www.stonebranch.com/solutions/docker-workload-automation/)